# How va_list and company work?

Tags: objective-c, low-level, variadic-functions

Currently i try to create a small trampoline for Objective-C IMP function. This function receive a variadic list of arguments. And i try to resend all parameters from trampoline to imp. So, `va_start(ap,argument)` return list of pointers. How parameters are allocated on stack and how can i get it from there?

Comment: Have you thought about making your life easier and using NSArray or NSMutableArray for this?

Comment: Target IMP is unknown, caller IMP is unknown, i need to inject into system code. NSArray are unacceptable way

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html might help you out.

Comment: default IMP implementation does not have vIMP pair.